# Can a user's AppleID be used to store custom data?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Is it possible to store custom data tied to a user's AppleID, e.g. information about activated products?

The task at hand is an App with digital content which can be bought via In-App purchases. The content is also available as a hardcopy (outside of the App); a buyer of the book will receive a coupon code with the book to activate this content in the App for free.

As far as I understand there are no free In-App purchases, so we will have to track the activated coupons ourselves (device-only storage is not enough – e.g. when the user upgrades his device). We would like to avoid introducing some sort of User account to store this data since it wouldn't be needed anywhere else. Therefore the idea: is there a way to use the User's AppleID to associate this data with?

Or, could you think of a different approach that won't introduce too much hassle for the user?

Any thoughts and ideas are highly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the iCloud to store any data that the user have. For you, would be all the coupons he has. Which, i believe, would be a simple text. iCloud comes with the iOS itself.. so you won't need to make your user create an account.

Comment: Definitely a good idea, thanks! Unfortunately the publisher currently wants the App to run on iOS 4, but I guess this point might change his mind...

Comment: @JulianD. If you manage to change the customer's idea and allow iOS 5 and up, you'll win a lot.

Comment: Actually, a user does not need to have iCloud enabled, does he? So unfortunately it's not a complete solution, hm.

Comment: The user doesn't need to have iCloud enabled indeed. Still, you can guide your user database to do so. Apple doesn't provide you a list of users who bought your app.. but you could do a search to see how Push Notifications works. Because it spams to all users that allowed it to receive informations from your app and check for yourself if you can do some trick to get data... but i don't know if it's approved!